# pycparser parse error on multi-byte character

Tags: python-3.x, pycparser

I'm using pycparser to parse some C code. Specifically code that can contain Japanese character inside characters and string such as below:

```
int main()
{
    char ch = '本';
}
```

I have tried to compile this on Dev-c, and compiles properly. 
Is this possible with pycparser?

Answer (score 0):

What issues are you observing? I think it's working:

```
$ cat /tmp/45.c
int main()
{
    char ch = '本';
}
$ python3 examples/dump_ast.py /tmp/45.c 
FileAST: 
  FuncDef: 
    Decl: main, [], [], []
      FuncDecl: 
        TypeDecl: main, []
          IdentifierType: ['int']
    Compound: 
      Decl: ch, [], [], []
        TypeDecl: ch, []
          IdentifierType: ['char']
        Constant: char, '本'
```

Comment: I get the following error, 
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pycparser\plyparser.py", line 67, in _parse_error
    raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: ./multi.c:3:15: Invalid char constant 'æœ¬'

Comment: I'm using version 2.19 anyway

Comment: I'm also using gcc as my preprocessor

Comment: I got this to work, it was my mistake, I used an incorrect encoding to read the file in the first place.